# script to allow user to highlight elemtents

Tags: keyboard, navigation

I am looking for a script to allow for keyboard navigation of various elements on a page. Basically the same functionality as if the user were to hover over with the mouse. Being able to make an element active through the keyboard, then be able to press enter to visit the link.

Does anything like this exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Scott Hanselman blogged about this. 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWebIsTheNewTerminalAreYouUsingTheWebsKeyboardShortcutsAndHotkeys.aspx

He recommends KeyTips jQuery Plugin:
http://damianedwards.com/files/KeyTips/

He also mentions HotKeys:
Link omitted because I am a new user and have already added two links.

Of course, you can always tab to navigate through links.